# Find vmaddr_slide of main app binary externally (Apple iOS)

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, jailbreak, tweak

is there any way to find vmaddr_slide of main app binary externally? i'm on jailbroken iOS and already obtained read/write to app. i've obtained header address of app via checking the first region in app (vm_region_64)

i'm iterating app's regions via vm_region_64_recurse and first region should be the app's header address
when i'm reading magic bytes from it, it outputs correctly. However, if i will try read something from __DATA section it will produce bad result (0x2/0x0, when it should be a pointer)

Comment: How are you trying to read from `__DATA`? Just by hardcoded address? If you have the app statically somewhere and take the difference between `__TEXT` and `__DATA`, then add that to the header address, you should get to the data segment at runtime.